# Python equivalent for @ApiCacheControl GAE endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In java you can control the cache of a endpoint method using @ApiCacheControl. I didn't see anything like that for the python SDK.

The only alternative is use the memcache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Appengine Java doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations) states:

> Note: The Javadoc lists some annotations that are currently not implemented. These annotations are: **ApiCacheControl**, and ApiFrontendLimits.

Probably, that means it's not available for Python, either.